# UTF-8 decoded text gets converted to encoded when appending

Tags: python, utf-8, encode

This is my code, and I am scraping some content from a website. I am fairly new to python.

```
for x in desc:
  rough_string = tostring(x,encoding='UTF-8')
  description.append(rough_string)

description = ''.join(description)
```

Here, `rough_string`gives proper output with special characters. But if I print `description`, it is utf8 encoded and I get characters like \xc3\x9c in the text.

I tried `description.encode("windows-1252").decode("utf-8")` and it gives me error.
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)`

I tried using `latin1` also, and I get the same error.

It outputs properly when I print `rough_string` within the loop.

Any help?

Comment: Are you using Python 2? If you're starting with Python, there's no reason at all to learn Python 2 – it's being discontinued in a few weeks. You should make sure you are running Python 3 (ideally at least Version 3.5).

Comment: You need to make this a [MCVE]; right now, we don't know for sure what type each `x` has, how `tostring` is defined (is it converting from `str` to `unicode`, or from `unicode` to `str`?), what OS/locale you're running on, confirmation of which version of Python you're running (almost certainly Python 2, but good to be clear) etc. I've got an idea of what is *probably* going on, but can't be sure.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the issue in that you iterate over each char of your bytes string.

Python3 solution for your encoding issue:

```
# your bytes as string
bytes_string = "\xc3\x9c"
# encode in latin-1 then decode in utf-8
s.encode("latin-1").decode("utf-8")
# result
# 'Ü'
```

Hope this helps !